# compare strings using sscanf, but ignore whitespaces

Tags: c, scanf

For a command line application I need to compare the input string to a command pattern. White spaces need to be ignored.

This line should match input strings like " drop   all  " and " drop all":

```
int rc = sscanf( input, "drop all");
```

But what does indicate a successful match here?

Comment: You seem to have chosen a wrong tool for the job...

Comment: @EugeneSh. maybe, but some commands also take numbers etc. as arguments. So this is a special case with no arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `"%n"` to record where the scanning stopped.

Add white space in the format to wherever WS in `input` needs to be ignored.

```
int n = -1;
sscanf( input, " drop all %n", &n);
//  v---- Did scanning reach the end of the format? 
//  |         v---- Was there additional text in `input`? 
if (n >= 0 && input[n] == '\0') Success();
```

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't understand what this code is doing without the requirement given in the question.

Comment: Will this work with `drop    all` and ` drop all ` ? (comments parser seems to be broken...)

Comment: @VTT: Why don't you try it?  It isn't hard to type, and copy'n'paste makes it even easier.  The blanks in the format string match 0 or more white space characters — blanks, tabs, newlines, for example.  And Markdown makes it hard to get the result you want with back-ticks and spaces (or other back-ticks).

Comment: @vtt Try `int n = -1;
  sscanf( "drop all", " drop all %n", &n);
  printf("%d\n", n);
  sscanf( " drop all ", " drop all %n", &n);
  printf("%d\n", n);`  What do you get?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Added some comments.  `"%n"` is a very useful specifier with the `*scanf()` family.

Comment: @chux I guess this solution only works ignoring *extra* whitespace, not just ignoring whitespace. for example `"drop all"` and `"dropall"` won't match.

Comment: @vtt This _will_ pass `input = "dropall"` as well as `"drop all"` - OP did say ignore all WS.  But if the input must have a space between the two words, no problem: Use format `" drop%*1[ /t]all %n"`.

Comment: @VTT-- note that a whitespace directive causes `scanf()` to skip over zero or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than working with dirty data, it's often better to clean it up and then work with it. Cleanup has to only happen once, whereas dirty data adds code complexity every time you have to use it. This step is often referred to as "normalization". Normalize the input to a canonical form before using it.

Clean up the input by trimming whitespace and doing whatever other normalization is necessary (such as folding and normalizing internal whitespace).

You could write your own trim function, but I'd recommend you use a pre-existing function like [Gnome Lib's g_strstrip()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strstrip). Gnome Lib brings in all sorts of handy functions.

```
#include <glib.h>

void normalize_cmd( char *str ) {
    g_strstrip(str);

    // Any other normalization you might want to do, like
    // folding multiple spaces or changing a hard tab to
    // a space.
}
```

Then you can use `strcmp` on the normalized input.

```
// This isn't strictly necessary, but it's nice to keep a copy
// of the original around for error messages and such.
char *cmd = g_strdup(input);

normalize_cmd(cmd);

if ( strcmp(cmd, "drop all") == 0) {
    puts("yes");
}
else {
    puts("no");
}
```

Putting all the normalization up front reduces the complexity of all downstream code having to work with that input; they don't have to keep repeating the same concerns about dirty data. By putting all the normalization in one place, rather than scattered all over the code, you're sure it's consistent, and the normalization method can be consistently updated.

Comment: `strcmp("drop\tall", "drop all")` will not match.  Typically such "clean-up" include a pass to convert multiple _white space_ to a single `' '`.

Comment: @chux Sure. Do any additional cleanup and normalization before working with the data.

Comment: It a 2-edged sword.  Clean-up as suggested is good for subsequent processing, yet original input is useful for logging and debug.  As with any user input, it is evil and should not be used until vetted.

Comment: It seems like `trim_left()` could lead to trouble if `strlen()` is used on the result to determine available space for, e.g., `strcat()`....

Comment: @DavidBowling You didn't read the comment, did you. Nobody reads the comments. :)

Comment: @chux You can hang on to a copy of the original if you like. Or log it then alter it.

Comment: If you mean the comment in code about better not to write your own cleanup functions, etc., yes I read that; just pointing out what seemed to be a potential issue lurking about :)

Comment: @DavidBowling I took my own advice and eliminated my home-rolled version, it's a distraction.